# Trying to compare two rows and then add cells in each using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare, rows

I have a list of stock items that have both new and refurbished parts.  New they both have the same part number except for refurbished parts have an R at the end.  I want to find the two rows and then add how many each have.  i.e.

- item#    description                       min     on hands
- 172077  Patch    Cable CAT 6, Molded -      4      2
- 172077R 172079 Patch Cable CAT              6      11

So I want to take both the on hands and add them..  together in the script than it will print one row out in a tab that tell me how many to order

I have the script working on a individual bases but it doesnt compare like parts so then it is telling me to order parts i dont need.  I only need to keep the item in stock doesnt matter if its new or old

```
//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Needs Ordered @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  function needsOrderedSheet() {
  // source spreadsheets
  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Products'); 
 //destination spreadsheet
 var destinationSpreadSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Needs Ordered'); 
//  destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow(['Item #','Description','Type','Min Stock','When To Order','On Order','Portal On Hands','Total In Stock','How Many to Order']);

  var startRow=2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows =2; // Number of rows to process
  var startColumn = 1;  // A=1 B=2
  var numColumns = 9;  // Number of columns to process

  var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
     var column = data[i];
    var itemnum = column[0]; // a column
    var desc = column[1]; // b column
    var type =column[2]; // c column
    var minstock = column[3]; // d column
    var whentoorder=column[4];// e column
    var onorder=column[5];// f column
    var portal = column[6]; // g column
    var compare= column
    var newitem = itemnum.split("R");
    var nitem=newitem[0];

  var dataRange2 = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
  var data2 = dataRange2.getValues();    
    for (var c = 0; c < data2.length; ++c) {
   var compare = data2[c];
   var itemnum2 = compare[0]; // a column
   var desc2 = compare[1]; // b column
   var type2 =compare[2]; // c column
   var minstock2 = compare[3]; // d column
   var whentoorder2=compare[4];// e column
   var onorder2=compare[5];// f column
   var portal2 = compare[6]; // g column
   var addp=portal + portal2;   
      var totalwhentoorder=whentoorder+whentoorder2;
      var totalminstock=minstock+minstock2;
      var instock = addp; // h column
      var totalonorder=onorder + onorder2;
      var howmanytoorder=totalminstock-(totalonorder+instock);

 if (nitem == itemnum2 && itemnum2 != '' && nitem != itemnum){
  if(instock <= whentoorder && whentoorder >= '1' && totalonorder < totalwhentoorder || instock < totalminstock && instock < whentoorder){

 destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,totalminstock,totalwhentoorder,totalonorder,portal,instock,howmanytoorder,nitem]);
 }

    }    

  if (nitem == itemnum && itemnum != '' && nitem != itemnum2){
   if(instock <= whentoorder && whentoorder >= '1' && totalonorder < totalwhentoorder || instock < totalminstock && instock < whentoorder){
   destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,totalminstock,totalwhentoorder,totalonorder,portal,instock,howmanytoorder,itemnum2]);
 }
     }    
    }
 //   }
 }
}
```

I updated the code.. This actually works the way I want for the first two rows but if I change the NumRows to 100 it basically just process the first two rows again..

Comment: title         item#      description                               min              on hands
row 1    172077 Patch Cable CAT 6, Molded -     4                     2 
row 2    172077R 172079 Patch Cable CAT        6,                   11

Comment: YES h column is actually g.. that part doesnt matter im the only one that sees the code..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: this `whentoorder >= '1'` should be this `whentoorder >= 1`

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency here: `if (setform != "Yes"){
      var instock = column[6]; // h column`  `else{
      var instock = column[7]; // h column`

Comment: what's this `var compare= column`  in the first loop

Comment: that shouldnt be there.. i must have forgot to remove it..

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6o05Sa-x9uhwj2WrLydPzhbcEBD2pkGJ-BRAS0LtoI/edit?usp=sharing   Here is a link to a copy of the sheet i am working on.. the sheet im working with is the needsordered sheet and you can reset using the reset needs ordered under the my custom menu.  the code i run in the script is the needsorderedsheet function

Answer (score 0):

## Comparing New and Refurbished Stock Items

```
function search1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet105');//sheet where I copied your data
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());//Data Range after Header
  var vA=rg.getValues();//all data
  var vB=[];
  var s=0;
  for(var i=0;i-s<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i-s][0].toString().slice(-1)=='R') {
      vB.push(vA[i - s]);//push Rs into vB
      vA.splice(i - s,1);//removing Rs from vA 
      s+=1;
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {//looking for vB in vA
    for(var j=0;j<vB.length;j++) {
      if(vA[i][0]==vB[j][0].toString().slice(0,-1)) {
        vB[j][7]=vA[i][6]+vB[j][6];//put sum in added column
      }  
    }
  }
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i-d<vB.length;i++) {//removing vB rows that are not long enough
    if(!vB[i-d][7]) {
      vB.splice(i-d,1);
      d++;
    }
  }
  //Putting vBs found in vA at bottom of spreadsheet.
  //The last column vB[j][7] is the sum of vA[i][6] and vB[j][6] from above
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 2,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
}
```

These are the lines I found.

[image]

This version will find the matches, sum the two in the R version and delete the non R version and make a who new list.  It also utilizes an output page that it clears before each run.  You have two assign the name of the pages.  The input page has to contain just the data (no other stuff on that page) and the output page will be cleared before writing on it again.

```
function search1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet109');
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet110');
  osh.clearContents();
  var vH=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=[];
  var s=0;
  //rg.sort({column:1,ascending:true});
  for(var i=0;i-s<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i-s][0].toString().slice(-1)=='R') {
      vB.push(vA[i - s]);
      vA.splice(i - s,1);
      s+=1;
    }
  }
  s=0;
  for(var i=0;i-s<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vB.length;j++) {
      if(vA[i-s][0]==vB[j][0].toString().slice(0,-1)) {
        vB[j][7]=vA[i-s][6]+vB[j][6];
        vA.splice(i-s,1);
        s+=1;
        break;
      }  
    }
  }
  var vBk=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i-d<vB.length;i++) {
    if(!vB[i-d][7]) {
      vBk.push(vB[i-d]);
      vB.splice(i-d,1);
      d++;
    }
  }
  osh.getRange(1,1,vH.length,vH[0].length).setValues(vH);
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,vBk.length,vBk[0].length).setValues(vBk);
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will test it out..  Sorry Im not a great programmer I mostly just find and modify to my liking.,.

Comment: I added your code into my script and it does work partially.. For some reason it prints out the 4 lines twice.. the end goal is to take all items on the product tab and if any items have less then min stock they print out..  combining any refurb and new parts so there not double ordered..   By the way the link above is a test project so you can make any changes to it..

Comment: There is other stuff in your sheet that is conflicting with my script and causing it to perform oddly.  Try running that script on the newly created Sheet15

Comment: Also keep in mind if you run it once then you have to delete it's output before you run it again.  Otherwise it will assume that everything on the page is part of data...even it's previous output.

Comment: This isn't a total solution for you.  It's just an example of how to separate the new and refurbished and how to find serial number matches between the two groups and  display the matches with 'on hand' summed.

Comment: Ya I know its not a total solution.. it actually should help.  I did see try it and it does seem to work when using sheet 15 wierd that it doesnt work with products but thats not that big a deal i can use stock items instead of the products tab

Comment: Thanks Cooper.. The last script seems to work pretty good.  I just have to get a few modifications to work. I just need to add the ability to total in stock and then do a how many to order field..  then Ill add a way to only show the ones that need ordered since in the end those are the ones i care about..

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of what I was looking for. Thanks to cooper for most of the code.  It finds the refurbished parts and new parts and joins them together. Then it only prints the items that needs ordered.

```
 function needsOrderedSheet() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Stock Items');
      var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Needs Ordered');
       osh.clearContents();
      var vH=(['Item #','Description','Type','Min Stock','On Order','Portal On Hands','Total In Stock','How Many to Order','New Part #']);
      var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,6);
      var vA=rg.getValues();
      var vB=[];
      var s=0;
      //rg.sort({column:1,ascending:true});
      for(var i=0;i-s<vA.length;i++) {
         vA[i-s][6]=vA[i-s][5];                                 // Total In Stock
         vA[i-s][7]=vA[i-s][3] - (vA[i-s][6] + vA[i-s][4]);     // How many to Order
      if(vA[i-s][0].toString().slice(-1)=='R') {

        vB.push(vA[i - s]);

          vA.splice(i - s,1);  
          s+=1;
        }
      }

      s=0;
      for(var i=0;i-s<vA.length;i++) {
         for(var j=0;j<vB.length;j++) {
           if(vA[i-s][0]==vB[j][0].toString().slice(0,-1)) {
            vB[j][6]=vA[i-s][5]+vB[j][5];                              //Total In Stock  vB
            vB[j][7]=vB[j][3] - (vA[i-s][4]+vB[j][6] + vB[j][4]);      //How many to Order  vB
            vB[j][8]=vA[i-s][0];                                      // Add New Part Number vB
            vA.splice(i-s,1);
             s+=1;
            break;
          }  
        }
      }
      var vBk=[];
      var d=0;
      for(var i=0;i-d<vB.length;i++) {
        if(!vB[i-d][8]) {

          vBk.push(vB[i-d]);
          vB.splice(i-d,1);
          d++;
        }
      }


    //  osh.getRange(1,1,vH.length,vH[0].length).setValues(vH)
     osh.appendRow(['Item #','Description','Type','Min Stock','On Order','Portal On Hands','Total In Stock','How Many to Order','Part # For New Items']);

     for(var c=0;c<vA.length;c++) {
       var vC = vA[c]; 
        var itemnum = vC[0]; // a column
        var desc = vC[1]; // b column
        var type =vC[2]; // c column
        var minstock = vC[3]; // d column
        var onorder=vC[4];// f column
        var portal =vC[5]; // g column
        var totalinstock=vC[6];
        var howmanytoorder=vC[7];
       var newpart=vC[8];

       if (howmanytoorder > 0){
      osh.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,minstock,onorder,portal,totalinstock,howmanytoorder,]);
       }
     }
    //   osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
      for(var d=0;d<vBk.length;d++) {
       var vD = vBk[d]; 
        var itemnum = vD[0]; // a column
        var desc = vD[1]; // b column
        var type =vD[2]; // c column
        var minstock = vD[3]; // d column
        var onorder=vD[4];// f column
        var portal =vD[5]; // g column
        var totalinstock=vD[6];
        var howmanytoorder=vD[7];
       var newpart=vD[8];

       if (howmanytoorder > 0){
      osh.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,minstock,onorder,portal,totalinstock,howmanytoorder,]);
       }
     }
    //  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,vBk.length,vBk[0].length).setValues(vBk);

      for(var e=0;e<vB.length;e++) {
         var vE = vB[e]; 
        var itemnum = vE[0]; // a column
        var desc = vE[1]; // b column
        var type =vE[2]; // c column
        var minstock = vE[3]; // d column
        var onorder=vE[4];// f column
        var portal =vE[5]; // g column
        var totalinstock=vE[6];
        var howmanytoorder=vE[7];
       var newpart=vE[8];

       if (howmanytoorder > 0){
      osh.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,minstock,onorder,portal,totalinstock,howmanytoorder,newpart]);
       }
     }
        //  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);

    }
```